# How do I convert text to XML in C?

Tags: c

How can I make a program that opens a text file, and converts it into a XML file?

The XML might look like:

```
<curso>
 <sigla>LTCGM</sigla>
 <NAlunos>1</NAlunos>
 <lista_alunos>
  <aluno>
   <numero>6567</numero>
   <nome>Artur Pereira Ribeiro</nome>
   <email>apereira@gmail.com</email>
   <estado>Aprovado</estado>
   <media_notas>13</media_notas>
   <maior_nota>16</maior_nota>
   <menor_nota>11</menor_nota>
  </aluno>
 </lista_alunos>
</curso>
```

Comment: That depends on the structure of your XML file.

Comment: What's your text look like? What's the XML supposed to look like? What have you tried so far and did you run into any specific problem? Your question is missing essential details and no one here is going to write you a converter ;)

Comment: <curso>
<sigla>LTCGM</sigla>
<NAlunos>1</NAlunos>
<lista_alunos>
<aluno>
<numero>6567</numero>
<nome>Artur Pereira Ribeiro</nome>
<email>apereira@gmail.com</email>
<estado>Aprovado</estado>
<media_notas>13</media_notas>
<maior_nota>16</maior_nota>
<menor_nota>11</menor_nota>
</aluno>
</lista_alunos>
</curso>

Comment: `printf ("<MyXml>%s</MyXml>", him);`

Comment: the txt file will be given by my teacher...i just need a start

Comment: <MyXml>...i have to include some library?

Comment: pedro the example you gavve should be made as an edit also what is the text file like

Answer (score 2):

Since XML is generally structured and a text file generally isn't, your first step is to write a parser that reads the text file and understands the structure of the text file. Since I don't know the format of your text file, I cannot give a more specific answer for that point.

Before you write the output, you must escape those characters that have a special meaning in XML, i.e. <, >, &.

Doing the actual output is done e.g. by fprintf, nothing special about that part.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do that - because it is not clear what structure is needed in the markup for the plain text.

What you can do, I suppose, is generate the XML tags on a first line, emit a quasi-arbitrary start tag, copy the file through, expanding XML key characters ('<', '>', '&') into the corresponding '<', '>', '&' notation, and then ending with the end tag corresponding to the start tag.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<start>
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
int main(void) { print("Hello, XML\n"); return 0; }
</start>
```

Anything more depends on knowledge of what's in the text file.